# Synonym of "blank out"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

More specifically, what could be the verb when you **blank out due to tension**? To be more elaborate, the tension could stop the wiring in your brain causing you to be confounded.

e.g. The interviewer's poker face just made me ______, I haven't answered anything at all and I don't think I have made it through the interview!

Comment: I found myself reaching for **freeze**.

Comment: What @SteveLovell said. [Become suddenly motionless or paralysed with fear or shock. ‘she froze in horror’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/freeze).

Comment: The close-to-panic response is what happens when people have stage fright.  There was a long article in the New Yorker about stage fright a few years ago.  It includes physical manifestations--e.g., cold hands.  You'd have to change the above to "gave me stage fright" to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Emboldened by support from @MikeJRamsey56, I'm converting my comment to an answer.

It has several other more "literal" meanings, but I'd suggest **Freeze**. One definition for which is:

> **Freeze**
>
> - Become suddenly motionless or paralysed with fear or shock.
>     ‘she froze in horror’
>
> Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/freeze)